# Is there a way to have two queries, as a part of JAVA implementation, to use the same data set?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, dataset

I am working on a Java Service (Hibernate) and I am calling sequentially a count query and a query to fetch the corresponding records (native queries). There are cases where the count is different than the actual records fetched by the query retrives the data.
I would like to secure that both queries are about to use the same dataset.
Any ideas on this?

Comment: Over time data changes. If you run the same query two times in a row the number of rows will naturally be different. Why don't you get the rows and count them?

Comment: I forgot to mention that I apply pagination, thus I would like to avoid getting rows and count them.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it is quite not good idea to use counts.
think about what primary key on record stands for... or maybe other fields identify records you need.
Retrieved Dataset on client gives you what was in DB at time you ran your query.
There are some dangerous abilities to lock table or records while your transaction not commited yet... but I do not recommend to try them. if it is about Db used by multiple services/clients or threads in parallel. I guess you have such system as counts change while your queries run.
It needs very careful handling to use locks and really dangerous to slow and hang other threads